# error log SIGABRT how to fix it?

Tags: iphone, xcode

when i insert this code it will make an error how can i handle event without error?

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            URLCacheAlertWithError(@"Result: canceled");
            //message.text = @"Result: canceled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            URLCacheAlertWithError(@"Result: saved");
            //message.text = @"Result: saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            URLCacheAlertWithError(@"Result: sent");
            //message.text = @"Result: sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            URLCacheAlertWithError(@"Result: failed");
            //message.text = @"Result: failed";
            break;
        default:
            URLCacheAlertWithError(@"Result: not sent");
        //  message.text = @"Result: not sent";
            break;
    }
}

2010-01-31 22:07:05.638 iPortals[1678:207] *** -[NSCFString localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x38474
2010-01-31 22:07:05.643 iPortals[1678:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString localizedDescription]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x38474'
2010-01-31 22:07:05.649 iPortals[1678:207] Stack: (
    844776241,
    843056877,
    844780055,
    844282517,
    844245696,
    20767,
    12345,
    807831445,
    807768071,
    807781201,
    844553639,
    807717485,
    844537573,
    851058789,
    851397973,
    844537573,
    851058789,
    851058693,
    851058647,
    851057969,
    851060293,
    851056221,
    851054649,
    851040559,
    851039143,
    848378745,
    844528685,
    844526429,
    848374975,
    848375147,
    850798447,
    850793587,
    9135,
    9068
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you have sent the message `localizedDescription` to an object at `0x38474` which is an object of class `NSCFString` which does not support this message.

You probably meant to send this method to another object that you have a pointer to, but did not retain this (probably autoreleased) object. It then got autoreleased and you send a message to the pointer (variable name), but some other method has placed an object at the same address.

Comment: i update some code for make that error at my post

thank for your reply Felix

Comment: The above method looks fine. Could you post the function URLCacheAlertWithError.

Comment: i see i know i use wrong argument of URLCacheAlertWithError
that cause of error
thanks again Felix